# configuring https for laravel on apache server

Tags: laravel, https, openssl, ubuntu-18.04

I've a vps on ovh with many sites configured via 
"sites-aviable.conf" (apache).

The thing to be considerated its that my vps have no domain name, but just a name provided from ovh, so if i try to use this on some authority that relase ssl certificate it can be used!
I need to set https instead of http for some site, so i start to generate a self-signed certificate with open ssl.
Then i check if the port 443 is in listen and its seems ok.
Then i change the `APP_URL` from http to https on .env file, but nothing change.

```
sites-aviable.conf
```

conteins something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AAAA/public
ServerName http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.net
Alias /web2 /var/www/html/BBBBB/public

<Directory /var/www/html/AAAAA>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all    
</Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/html/BBBBB>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all        
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

so this to me should be replicated even for the 443 port, or I wrong? (ive tried to rough change 80 to 443 but didnt work)

I try to add on the same "sites-aviable.conf"
this part:

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AAAAAAA/public
    ServerName http://XXXXXXXXXXX.net
    Redirect permanent / https://XXXXXX.net
```

on the `<VirtualHost *:80>` part, and then under I add just under this part:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443> 
ServerName https://XXXXXXXXXX.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AAAAAAAA/public
SSLEngine On 
</VirtualHost>
```

How can i set this to my server?

If im visiting the url with https i receive a apache error of "not found"

Comment: `APP_URL` is only for the CLI (commands) it has nothing to do with your site when served from a web server

Comment: @lagbox thanks! I found this soultion in many threads about laravel and https.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @neo87 AAAAA is a 5.4 laravel and BBBBB is 5.8

Comment: @lagbox One small correction: the `APP_URL` is used in the password reset notification, which is not queued, so it is sent from the site. That is the only non-CLI usage I know of for the value. But yes, nothing to do with the issue at hand here.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to support both http and https, you need to define a virtual host for both port 80 and port 443. However, inside your virtual host for port 443, you also need to specify your SSL Certificate File and SSL Certificate Key File.

So, just copy your http definition and update the port and SSL information. Your .conf file will look something like this (based on the VirtualHost definition you provided in your question.

```
# http
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AAAA/public
  ServerName xxxxxxxxxxxx.net
  Alias /web2 /var/www/html/BBBBB/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/AAAAA>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all    
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/BBBBB>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all        
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# https
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AAAA/public
  ServerName xxxxxxxxxxxx.net
  Alias /web2 /var/www/html/BBBBB/public

  # Your SSL configuration. Update the File and KeyFile information
  # below to point to your SSL certificate.
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key"

  <Directory /var/www/html/AAAAA>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all    
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/BBBBB>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all        
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you restart apache after updating your config.

Also, your https url should work now, but since you're using a self-signed certificate, your browser will still complain about it being unsafe and not trusted. I'm assuming this is for a dev environment, so that shouldn't be an issue. If this is for a production site that others are meant to use, then you should be getting a real SSL cert from a trusted authority (LetsEncrypt has free SSL certs).

Comment: thanks for this detailed reply, but still not works for me! i just mods the ssl part in this way: " SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key " but not works still 404 after apache reboot

Comment: @JahStation Does the same page at `http` page give you a 404?

Comment: @JahStation One other thing I just noticed: remove the scheme from the `ServerName` value. Should just be `xxxxxxxxxxxx.net`, not `http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.net`. Do this on both VirtualHost definitions. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: the thing with this mods change a little bit: after the update that suggest i see a page that tell that the site is "unsafe" then if i proceed the next page is still a 404! the http version working with or without the update of removing scheme.

Comment: ok im really lost: with this new config as suggested by @patricus if im visiting https://XXXXX.net (again is not a domain name but the name given by ovh to the machine) i see the content on /html folder  (after the espected warning of "unsafe area") and not the expexted "/var/www/html/AAAA/public" if i visiting the second one nothing works